# Simulink: code generation for a complex model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I create a model by Simulink+Stateflow (aaa). Then create another model (bbb) that uses two instance of the previous one.
Then I generate the code from the models to use it onto a phisical board.
The problem is that I have 2 files from model aaa (aaa.c and aaa.h) and three files from the model bbb (bbb.c, bbb.h and aaa.h) because aaa is used in bbb.
But the files aaa.h are different (there are some similarities, but each one is useful for aaa or bbb code).
So it is impossible for me to use the models together.

Does it exist a best practice to integrate the generate code?
Or does it exists a Simulink option to create directly all I need?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but something is going wrong. I followed your istructions... so I don't know if there is some misconfigurations in my project (yes, I'm using model reference) or in the destination environment. In fact Simulink generates two folders: aaa (conaining aaa.c, aaa.h) and bbb (containing bbb.c, bbb.h and a subfolder referenced_model_includes/aaa.h)... but in PSoc Creator I'm not able to import and build all these 5 files together...

Comment: What error do you get? As you say, it may be configuration issues either at the Simulink end, or at the IDE end. Difficult to tell, really.

Comment: It seems it's working (just compiling for now). I think the problem is due to the cohexistence of two different file with the same name (and the way used by PSoC Creator to manage user source files). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phil said, if you are using Model Reference (it sounds like you are), then it should do incremental build and code generation. Generate code for the top-level model and all models that are referenced by it will automatically generate code as well. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/examples/component-based-modeling-with-model-reference.html and http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2008/12/05/the-answer-for-large-scale-modeling-model-reference/ as examples.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in the comment of my post something is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are not using aaa independently of bbb (on your physical board) then you shouldn't be generating code for aaa independently from bbb.  Generating code for bbb (only) will detect that it needs to generate code for aaa and automatically create all the files you need (including the functionality of both bbb and aaa).

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in the comment of my post something is going wrong.